Perturbing Differential Equation While Using Torchdiffeq
I am trying to find the largest Lyapunov exponent for a high-order ODE and thus have to perturb the dynamics by some small number at a certain time point. Until now, I have been able to utilize GPU using PyTorch and torchdiffeq library to solve this ODE. However, I cannot seem to find a way to perturb certain variables while solving the ODE using torchdiffeq's odeint function. Without utilizing torchdiffeq, the calculations are too slow.
I have tried to use a Dirac delta function-styled method, where I added epsilon * inf to the input function of odeint (representing dy/dt) at a certain time point, but I had little success. Plus, this method seems to slow down the calculations quite a lot. Is there any other way of tackling this problem?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
